# Getting more than the value of option tag from select element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app, I have a `select` tag to select some options. The options are fetched from an API and mapped as shown bellow.

```
 <select
   id="numberbase__select"
   onChange={this.onSelectExistingNumberBase}>
            <option selected disabled hidden>Select a number base</option>
                  {this.props.tenantNumberBases.NumberBases.map((value, index) => {
                    return (
                        <option value={value.uuid}>{value.numberBaseName}</option>
                    );
                })}
 </select>
```

To change the value of this, I have used the following helper method.

```
onSelectExistingNumberBase = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        existingNumberBase: e.target.value
    });
}
```

This way I can get the `uuid` of the mapped array values. But in addition to `uuid`, I want to get the `numberBaseName` as well. I tried using `e.target.id`. But it did't work. I was able to get `uuid` because I have added it as the value of `option` tag. How can I get more values that `uuid`? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can `find` the selected item by the `uuid` easily:

```
onSelectExistingNumberBase = (e) => {
  let item = tenantNumberBases.NumberBases.find(el => el.uuid === e.target.value);
  this.setState({
    existingNumberBase: item
  });
}
```

Or if the performance is of concern just index the array into an object like:

```
// This:
let items = [
  { uuid: 1, numberBaseName: "a" },
  { uuid: 2, numberBaseName: "b" }
]

// To This:
let itemsIndexedByUUID = {
  1: { uuid: 1, numberBaseName: "a" },
  2: { uuid: 2, numberBaseName: "b" }
}
```

Then your handler will be simpler:

```
onSelectExistingNumberBase = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    existingNumberBase: itemsIndexedByUUID[e.target.value]
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked too. But I followed another way and it worked. I'll give the solution here as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There might be few ways to achieve this. But I'll post here the solution that helped me.

First in select option, code like this.

```
<select
   onChange={this.onSelectExistingNumberBase}>
   <option selected disabled hidden>Select a number base</option>
   {this.props.tenantNumberBases.NumberBases.map((value, index) => {
         return (
             <option value={value.uuid} id={value.numberBaseName}>{value.numberBaseName}</option>
         );
   })}
</select>
```

Then in the onChange helper method I followed something like following.

```
onSelectExistingNumberBase = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        existingNumberBase: e.target.value,
        numberBaseName: e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text,
    });
}
```

I was able to get options and then the value inside the option tag using selected index. I hope this will help someone who has the same problem.